# IntelliJ with JBoss, how to make JBoss see changes made without manually rebuilding and redeploying application?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, web-applications, jboss

I'm quite new developer and have an java application with several modules (several .jar and .war) files, which are build into one .ear. After one of the files change for example .jsp I have to rebuild and redeploy whole application, is there a possibility to see changes immediately (refresh, update or something, that changed code will be detected compiled, build and deployed automatically)?

Comment: IDE has out-of the-box functionality for hot update of running application, see [Updating Applications on Application Servers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need third-party tools for that. Most popular one is jRebel (see: https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/). It allows you to update most of your project files without redeploying whole application.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to want a different tool for that.  JRebel is a great one.  If you want to go lean more about it click [here](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/). Theres a few other tools you could go online and find I'm sure, but in my opinion JRebel is supreme.